# MonogoDB Replica Set Status Not changing from Startup to Secondary

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, replicaset

I have setup a MongoDB replica set  with 3 nodes(vm's running CentOS). One node became Primary other 2 stuck in Startup. When these 2 nodes will change their states from startup to secondary.

```
aryabhata:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "aryabhata",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-04-30T08:10:45.173Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "localhost.localdomain:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "uptime" : 69091,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1461935462, 1),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2016-04-29T13:11:02Z"),
                    "electionTime" : Timestamp(1461934754, 1),
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-04-29T12:59:14Z"),
                    "configVersion" : 459192,
                    "self" : true
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "repset1.com:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 0,
                    "stateStr" : "STARTUP",
                    "uptime" : 92,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-04-30T08:10:44.485Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "pingMs" : 0,
                    "configVersion" : -2
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "repset2.com:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 0,
                    "stateStr" : "STARTUP",
                    "uptime" : 68382,
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-04-30T08:10:43.974Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "pingMs" : 0,
                    "configVersion" : -2
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: any updates on this issue? is this fixed?

Answer (score 7):

My problem fix with set ip address for Primary instead hostname

```
cfg = rs.conf()
cfg.members[0].host = "public-or-private-primary-ip:27017" 
rs.reconfig(cfg)
```

after that secondary state change to STARTUP2

Answer (score 5):

From primary check whether you are able to connect to secondary

```
mongo --host repset1.com --port 27017
```

When the above one fails may be firewall or BindIP issue.

Check bind_ip (should be 0.0.0.0, change in mongodb.conf is it's 127.0.0.1):

```
netstat -plunt | grep :27017 | grep LISTEN
```

Look at the log-files of secondaries, why they are stuck. Did they receive the configuration details?

Try to reconfigure, see [mongo replicaset reconfigure](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/)

Comment: thanks for the reply. my secondaries did not receive the configuration details

Answer (score 3):

It requires that both the primary resolves the host name to IP of the secondary and also the secondary resolves the hostname of the primary to an IP.

In my case I forgot to add in hosts file for the secondary to resolve the hostname of the primary. Once I updated the hosts file in the secondary, the state of the secondary transitioned to STARTUP2 and then to SECONDARY.

Comment: That's it! Whlie I used rs.initiate() and then rs.add(<ip>:<port>) to add the secondaries, my primary host was defined with local hostname. Which was not resolvable to the secondaries. Reconfigured my primary member as follows: 

`cfg = rs.conf()`
`cfg.members[0].host = "<ip>:<port>"`
`rs.reconfig(cfg)`

and secondaries switched to next states.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that primary had authorization enabled. In this case the secondaries always stayed in `STARTUP`.

To use authorization you need to set `keyFile` in configuration file of all nodes (primary and secondary).

---

Create mongodb key file on linux:

```
openssl rand -base64 741 > mongodb.key
chmod 600 mongodb.key
chown mongod:mongod mongodb.key
```

mongod.conf file:

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0

security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /home/mongodb.key
```

Source [MongoDB replica set with simple password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524150/mongodb-replica-set-with-simple-password-authentication)