# MongoDB replica set with simple password authentication

Tags: mongodb, authentication, replicaset, database, nosql

I have a MongoDB replica set of 3 servers (1 primary, 1 secondary, 1 arbiter; this is the default replica set created by Google Cloud 1-click install). The 2 config files (mongod.conf) of primary server and secondary server have been changed with `security.authorization: enabled` added.

Root user is added with the following MongoDB shell command:

```
use admin
db.createUser({user:"root",pwd:"root",roles:["root"]})
```

After restarting MongoDB services on the primary and secondary servers with "sudo service mongod restart", connection to the replica set turns unstable.

rs.status() sometimes give the result as

- 1 primary, 1 unreachable, 1 arbiter
- 1 secondary, 1 secondary, 1 arbiter
- 1 secondary, 1 unreachable, 1 arbiter

**How to setup basic password authentication (not using keyfile) for MongoDB replica set the correct way?**

Comment: Please provide the full output of rs.status() which you are observing.

Comment: Also, can you be more specific about what you mean by "unstable"? Is the rs.status() observed constantly like this? Only for a sure period? Intermittent?

Comment: hey man actually i am facing an error `Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command`. You can also find my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783700/when-creating-first-admin-user-on-mongdb-cluster-getting-error-couldnt-add-use . It would be a lot much easier if you could tell me from which url(source) you have done this whole password authentication thing, please help me i have searched everywhere but didn't find anything ??

Comment: use admin first to authenticate, then db.auth('username','password')

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I finally found the answer. MongoDB replica set needs both user account and keyfile. Keyfile seems for authentication between servers in the replica set, not for logging in.

Create mongodb key file on linux, copy to all db servers with mode `600` intact:

```
cd
openssl rand -base64 741 > mongodb.key
chmod 600 mongodb.key
```

mongod.conf file:

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0

security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /home/USERNAME/mongodb.key
```

Admin user:

```
(just like in question content)
```

Comment: I have the same issue right now, I generated the key and provided it into individual .conf files, 4 in my case. now when i start the `mongod` without authentication it cant do `rs.initiate()` or create users. Do  you know why?

Comment: create user before creating replicaset, rs.initiate on first server only. "Use rs.initiate() on one and only one member of the replica set" -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

Comment: so basically run the first instance without `replication:`, create a admin user and then restart with `replication:` enabled and then run `rs.initiate()`?
When do I start the remaining instances?

Comment: hey man actually i am facing an error `Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command`. You can also find my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783700/when-creating-first-admin-user-on-mongdb-cluster-getting-error-couldnt-add-use . It would be a lot much easier if you could tell me from which url(source) you have done this whole password authentication thing, please help me i have searched everywhere but didn't find anything ??

Comment: To enforce authentication for existing replicate set https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/

Comment: This works ... trial and tested on production thanks for sharing