# When creating first admin user on mongdb cluster getting error "couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command"

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongoDB Cluster with version 3.4 in google cloud compute engine, actually past week my database got attacked by hackers that's why i thought about using authorization so that i can avoid these types of attack. Now to add Authorizations i saw this article [how-to-create-mongodb-replication-clusters](http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/database-servers/how-to-create-mongodb-replication-clusters/), now i have added a `keyfile` with `chmod 0600` on each of my cluster node, but now when i am trying to add my first `admin user` i am getting below error

```
use admin
switched to db admin
rs0:PRIMARY> db.createUser({user: "RootAdmin", pwd: "password123", roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]});
2017-01-21T18:19:09.814+0000 E QUERY    [main] Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute comm
and { createUser: "RootAdmin", pwd: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ], digestPassword: false, writ
eConcern: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 300000.0 } } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1290:15
@(shell):1:1
```

I have searched everywhere but haven't found anything on why i am getting this error.

Can anyone please help me how can i solve this error.

**UPDATE**
My config file is given below for each of the instances

**Secondary Server Config**

```
#!/bin/bash
# mongod.conf
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: false
   #engine:
  mmapv1:
    smallFiles: true
#  wiredTiger:
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
#processManagement:
security:
  authorization: disabled
  keyFile: /opt/mongodb/keyfile
#operationProfiling:
#replication:
#sharding:
## Enterprise-Only Options:
#auditLog:
#snmp:
```

**Arbiter Server Config**

```
#!/bin/bash
# mongod.conf
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /mnt/mongodb/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
   #engine:
  #mmapv1:
    #smallFiles: true
#  wiredTiger:
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /mnt/mongodb/log/mongodb.log
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
#processManagement:
security:
  authorization: disabled
  keyFile: /opt/mongodb/keyfile
#operationProfiling:

#replication:
#sharding:
## Enterprise-Only Options:
#auditLog:
#snmp:
```

**Primary Server Config**

```
#!/bin/bash
# mongod.conf
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /mnt/mongodb/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
   #engine:
  #mmapv1:
    #smallFiles: true
#  wiredTiger:
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /mnt/mongodb/log/mongodb.log
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
#processManagement:
security:
  authorization: disabled
  keyFile: /opt/mongodb/keyfile
#operationProfiling:

#replication:
#sharding:
## Enterprise-Only Options:
#auditLog:
#snmp:
```

Comment: just a notice, u have a password shown in the question

Comment: Did you get this fixed? If so, please update or answer yourself. Did you inspect the log files - there might be a clue in there.

Answer (score 19):

You have to change your **mongod.conf** file to disable authorization before creating such admin user

```
security:
  authorization: disabled
```

After that, **restart the mongod service** and open mongodb shell to create the admin user

```
use admin
db.createUser({user:"RootAdmin",pwd:"blahblah",roles:["root"]})
```

**Remember to enable authorization back on after creating user.**

Comment: I have added `authorization: disabled` but still facing same error. I have updated my config files for all of my instances. Can you please tell me the source url or whole procedure of adding authentication in mongoDB replicasets also thanks for helping me out of here.

Comment: that's strange, when authorization is disabled, u can do anything

Comment: can you tell me your source(url) where you have done this whole authentication thing ??

Answer (score 4):

[johnlowvale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5581893/johnlowvale)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41789745/1414479) is correct, but

```
keyFile implies security.authorization.
```

source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.keyFile

You have to disable authorization AND the keyFile.

```
security:
  authorization: disabled
# keyFile: /opt/mongodb/keyfile
```

(insufficient rep or I'd have just commented this on johnlowvale's answer)

Comment: Had the same problem as OP and the `keyFile implies security.authorization.` -- This is the ticket and the cause of the whole situation. Thanks that small line of text solved all my issues.

Comment: yes this is correct, you should be commenting keyFile as well !!

Answer (score 3):

Once you are connected to this first node, you can initiate the replica set with rs.initiate(). Again, this command must be run from the same host as the mongod to use the localhost exception.

We can create our admin user with the following commands:

```
rs.initiate()
use admin
db.createUser({
  user: "admin",
  pwd: "pass",
  roles: [
    {role: "root", db: "admin"}
  ]
})
```

Comment: `rs.initiate()` saved me.

Answer (score 1):

edit `vim /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`

```
remove --auth 
restart

#ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --auth   --config /etc/mongod.conf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet  --config /etc/mongod.conf
use admin
db.createUser({user:"RootAdmin",pwd:"blahblah",roles:["root"]})
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to create a new user, you need to first disable security in /etc/mongod.conf

`// security:
//  authorization: enabled`

Then restart Mongodb server

`sudo service mongo restart`

After this you can add the user and role that you want from the shell.

`db.createUser({
    user: 'test_user',
    pwd: 'test',
      roles: [
                { role: "userAdmin", db: "test" },
                { role: "dbAdmin",   db: "test" },
                { role: "readWrite", db: "test" }
             ]
})`

To enable authenticated connection
Uncomment the line again in /etc/mongod.conf

`security:
  authorization: enabled`

and restart the server again

Answer (score 0):

When a new database is setup with authorisation/security enabled but no users set up, you can only connect to it from the localhost.  In your config file you should have bind ip set to 127.0.0.1 I think in order to make sure you connect to it with the correct authorisation to create new users.

This is what it says in Mongo course M103

By default, a mongod that enforces authentication but has no configured users only allows connections through the localhost.