# How to change from Startup to Secondary in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I need help on how to change the STARTUP to SECONDARY in MongoDB. I added 3 nodes and 2 nodes must be on SECONDARY state but unfortunately it became STARTUP after adding it. See details below. Been looking for an answer but nothing seems the same with my currently problem.

Hi everyone. I need help on how to change the STARTUP to SECONDARY in MongoDB. I added 3 nodes and 2 nodes must be on SECONDARY state but unfortunately it became STARTUP after adding it. See details below. Been looking for an answer but nothing seems the same with my currently problem.

```
members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      name: 'svplred1:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 3786,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1707380305, i: 1 }), t: Long('4') },
      optimeDate: ISODate('2024-02-08T08:18:25.000Z'),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate('2024-02-08T08:18:25.168Z'),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate('2024-02-08T08:18:25.168Z'),
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1707376535, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate('2024-02-08T07:15:35.000Z'),
      configVersion: 3,
      configTerm: 4,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: '10.0.14.17:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 0,
      stateStr: 'STARTUP',
      uptime: 3785,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long('-1') },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long('-1') },
      optimeDate: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate('2024-02-08T08:18:28.791Z'),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      pingMs: Long('0'),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: -2,
      configTerm: -1
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: '10.0.14.18:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 0,
      stateStr: 'STARTUP',
      uptime: 2895,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long('-1') },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long('-1') },
      optimeDate: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate('2024-02-08T08:18:28.918Z'),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
      pingMs: Long('0'),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: -2,
      configTerm: -1
    }   ]
```

Comment: STARTUP is temporary state , it need to move to SECONDARY automatic after init sync , perhaps you have issue in the configuration , check this ticket for some tips : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952564/monogodb-replica-set-status-not-changing-from-startup-to-secondary

Comment: As recommended by MongoDB you should created members with their hostname rather than their IP-Address. See [Deploy a Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#hostnames)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are affected by this:

Starting in MongDB 5.0,
split horizon DNS
nodes that are only configured with an IP address fail startup validation and report an error. See [disableSplitHorizonIPCheck](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.disableSplitHorizonIPCheck).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue. My primary must be also an IP address. it resolved my problem. Thank you everyone for all your suggestions. :)